# How to select multiple name from one row?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my table look like

```
Table A-----------------
ID . Color . IDDOCT
 1 .   Red . 3
 2 .  Blue . 2,4
 3 .  Cyan . 4
------------------------

Table B-----------------
ID . NAME
 1 . HAARIS
 2 . STEAVE
 3 . DONY
 4 . CLAYS
------------------------
```

What i'm asking is can i get the name of Table B on multiple ID in Table A and i need to show up on table php.

Comment: you have to read about [SQL Joins](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/)

Comment: how to join field with multiple id?

Comment: review [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql join on csv field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009872/mysql-join-on-csv-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is tested and works just fine:

```
$sql = 'SELECT table_a.color AS a_color, GROUP_CONCAT(table_b.name) AS b_names FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON FIND_IN_SET(table_b.id, table_a.iddoct) GROUP BY table_a.color';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

SQL :

```
SELECT A.ID,A.Color, group_contact(B.NAME)
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON FIND_IN_SET(A.IDDOCT, B.ID)
```

I Hope It will help you..